# Error on installation for node app.js at Linux Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, bcrypt, node-pre-gyp

Hi Good Morning && Good Afternoon,

After changed the mode of /usr/bin/env to 776, I have still encountered this error. Is it related with bcrypt error or anything else? Would you be able to fix my problem?

root@ip:/nodejs/blocknet# npm install

> bcrypt@5.1.0 install /nodejs/blocknet/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/ch                                                                                                                                                             okidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@                                                                                                                                                             2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}                                                                                                                                                             )
npm WARN veriple@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.1.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                                                                                             ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-09T10_56_53_583Z-debug.log

Comment: Please do research and produce what you did.